# Find the equation of the tangent plane to the level surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

(a) Find the equation of the tangent plane to the level surface $V (x, y, z) = V (3, 4, 5)$
at the point whose $x$ and $y$-coordinates are $3$ and $4$, respecively, where $$V (x, y, z) = 5x^2-3xy+xyz.$$

What I have done is first calculate $\nabla V(3,4,0)=(10x-3y+yz,xy-3x,xy)$.

Then $\nabla V=(10\cdot 3-3\cdot 4+0,3,12)=(18,3,12)$. This is the normal vector to the tangent plane, so the the equation of the tangent plane is $18x+3y+12z=(3, 4, 5)(3,4,0)=126$...I don't know if it is right.

(b) What is the rate of change of the electrical potential if the particle starts to follow
the direction given by any vector parallel to that plane?
Have no ideal about that

Comment: Can you explain where $(3,4,0)$ comes from?

Comment: that's the point I confused now..only two points x,y=(3,4). but ∇V contains 3 variables

Comment: As my edit suggests, I think you're supposed to find the point on the surface whose $x$ and $y$ coordinates are $3$ and $$$. This point is not $(3,4,0)$.

Comment: Now I've been out of college for a while and was awful at calculus when I was in school but I'm a gluten for punishment and would like to just ask this. Am I way off here when I see V(3,4,5) and then see that they are looking for z at x=3,y=4. So all math aside I want to look at that and say z=5. This being my gut reaction makes me feel that's wrong.(That's generally how Calc went for me. If I followed my gut reaction I was wrong. :p) So what rule is missing from this picture?
On a related tangent. Is there a place I could re teach myself Calc?

Comment: So to answer my own question I found this 
`z = f(x, y) =  x^2 + xy + y^2` on wikipedias Partial derivative page. Does this equation apply to this question? (Guess I'm sort of answering my question with a question. :/ I am bad at this.)